# Not able to find Face and FaceRecognition classes

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I am working on Face Recognition java project using OpenCV 3.4.0. For that using createFisherFaceRecognizer(0,1500) method but OpenCV doesn't contain this class and method. Does anyone know about OpenCV? Please let me know how to use it.

These are imports

```
import org.opencv.face.Face;
import org.opencv.face.FaceRecognizer;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another thing called OpenCV-contrib that is required to run the following Face class .

This is the GitHub repo [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) . Read the README.md

Follow the given steps : -

1. Download the original OpenCV  [repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) and the contrib repo from GitHub.
2. Go to  opencv_contrib/modules/face and open cmakeLists.txt with any editor . Now find the line that begins with ocv_define_module and add the word 'java' (no quotes) in the end .

   [Looks like:-

   ocv_define_module(face opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_objdetect WRAP python java)]

3.Compile using cmake using this : cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=path to opencv_contrib

Use the generated jar!

PS:In windows , I don't think the default .exe opencv installer contains the face classes , so its better to build with cmake .

Comment: what should I give in CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and how to give a path OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH and one more path to opencv_contrib.

Comment: can you one sample of the 3rd option.

Answer (score 0):

`org.opencv.face` is not available with *OpenCV*. For that, `opencv-contrib` is required which can be easily added. Follow the link:

[opencv-contrib library](https://answers.opencv.org/question/198453/is-there-a-way-to-use-opencv-contrib-modules-with-android-native/)